# Bash shell linux how to detect name of the extention files (flv) (ass)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to create a script to mux video (flv) subtitle (.ass) automatically without user intervention

Exemple 
the script detect two files with the same name (.flv) (.ass)

```
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre 1.mp4
~/Vidéos/vidéo numéro 1.ass
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre 2.mp4
~/Vidéos/vidéo numéro 2.ass
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre x.ass
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre x.mp4
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre zz.mp4
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre xy.ass
```

and get this

```
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre 1.mkv
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre 2.mkv
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre x.mkv
~/Vidéos/vidéo numbre zz.mkv
```

...

how to détect name of the files with extention .flv .ass with the same folder of the script and mux with my commande line

```
ffmpeg -i "${name}.flv" -vcodec copy -acodec copy mkvtemp.mkv
mkvmerge -v -o "${name}.mkv" --default-track 0 --language 0:fre "${name}.ass" mkvtemp.mkv
```

tx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
find . -name "*.mp4" | while read line
do
   name=`basename "$line" .mp4`
   ffmpeg -i "${name}".flv -vcodec copy -acodec copy mkvtemp.mkv
   mkvmerge -v -o "${name}".mkv --default-track 0 --language 0:fre "${name}".ass mkvtemp.mkv
done
```

This should work with filenames containing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in `ls | rev | cut -f2- -d. | rev | sort | uniq`; do
  ffmpeg -i "${name}.flv" -vcodec copy -acodec copy mkvtemp.mkv
  mkvmerge -v -o "${name}.mkv" --default-track 0 --language 0:fre "${name}.ass" mkvtemp.mkv
done
```

Replace `ls` with whatever you used to output the list of files.

Comment: you have a partial solution :) ths code not limite extension files and and not supporting the special character and space with the name sorry i forgot to tell this infomation – and look ma demo script http://pastebin.com/L0icKit8